# webRTC Video and Audio Call in Flutter

Tags: flutter, webrtc, simplewebrtc, openwebrtc, openwebrtcdemo

I am new to Flutter App and I have to create a WEBRTC based video and audio calling app for both IOS and Android without using TURN Server with FCM for creating a connection between 2 users.
Could anyone please help me out how can we achieve this functionality?
Need something very similar to Peer js.
Any docs or videos explaining it will also help.

Comment: https://developers.connectycube.com/flutter/videocalling

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an existing plugin specific on the implementation of [webRTC using Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc). As for the tutorials, try to check the [webRTC codelab](https://webrtc.org/getting-started/firebase-rtc-codelab) and good video tutorial about ["Realtime Communication with WebRTC in Flutter & Dart"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAKQzNQmNe0).